# Using Atlassian SourceTree, error during stash apply. Not sure what to do

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-stash

I clicked "apply stash" and I got the following error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false stash apply stash@{0}
fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash@0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

What can I do? SourceTree shows my stash as existing, but does it really? Is there a way I can restore what was in the stash? I'm very new to stashes. Could I apply my stash from command-line git instead (assuming it still exists)?

Answer (score 4):

Found answer on [this](http://ariejan.net/2008/04/23/git-using-the-stash/) page.

Used following command and all is well:

```
git stash apply stash@{0}
```